# Graph has unconnected nodes

Tags: python, graph, networkx

So, I'm still new at python, but I wrote this function to generate a graph that has certain hierarchical features. But, sometimes this function creates a graph with an unconnected node(s). But this should not be happening because every node should be fully connected with the other nodes below its "level". The characteristics of the hierarchical follow those of Seigel 2009: "The base is a hierarchy determined by the parameter Expansion Rate in which one individual is placed at the top, and each individual in the network is connected to a number of individuals below him equal to Expansion Rate, continuing until no more individuals are left in the population. Thus, while each level of the hierarchy before the last one contains a number of individuals equal to a power of Expansion Rate, the last level may have fewer than this if the total population does not divide appropriately. Each potential tie between individuals within the same level also has a probability equal to Level Connection of being made."

```
def heirarchy_graph(n,e,l):
    '''
    n is number of nodes in graph,
    e is the Expansion Rate. This is the number of people on each level
       If n/e has a remainder then the last level has that many
       people in it.
    l is the Level connection. It is the probability that a person is connected to someone
      within the level they belong to.
    '''
    G = nx.Graph()
    G.name="heirarchy_graph(%s,%s,%s)"%(n,e,l)

    r = (n-1)%e
    s = (n-r-1)/e
    h = s + 1
    #G = empty_graph(n=0)

    G.add_node(0, level=int(0))

    for i in range(s):
        list = range(1,(e+1))
        A = nx.Graph()
        #for item in list:
            #create e nodes with attribute level='i'
        A.add_nodes_from(list,level=int(i))

        # add edges between nodes with probability l
        names = A.nodes()

        for name in names:
            B = non_neighbors(A,name)
            for u in B:
                q = random.uniform(0,1)
                if q <= l:
                    A.add_edge(u,name)
        #return A
        #print(A)
        G = nx.disjoint_union(G,A)


    if r != 0: 
        h = s+1
        list = range(1,(r+1))
        A = nx.Graph()
        #create e nodes with attribute level='i'
        A.add_nodes_from(list,level=int(h))
        # add edges between nodes with probability l
        names = A.nodes()
        for name in names:
            B = non_neighbors(A,name)
            for u in B:
                q = random.uniform(0,1)
                if q <= l:
                    A.add_edge(u,name)


        G = nx.disjoint_union(G,A)

       ## add edges between levels
    level = nx.get_node_attributes(G,'level')
    names = G.nodes()
    for name in names:
        levelname = level[name]
        B = non_neighbors(G,name)

        for u in B:
            levelneighbor = level[u]
            if levelname == (levelneighbor + 1):
                G.add_edge(u,name)

    return G
```

I ran this code multiple times with n=25,e=5 and l=.5 but oftentimes I end up with nodes 21,22,23 or 24 (or some combination of them) being unconnected (checked by pulling each node's degree centrality).

I would greatly appreciate any help with this. The code runs without errors, I just don't know why it is giving me unconnected nodes. These nodes should be connected with the level above them. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure of your error on a quick scan, but why do you have `q = random.uniform(0,1)
            if q <= l:
                A.add_edge(u,name)` ?  This will always add an edge.  Why create a random number that is less than 1 and then test if it is less than 1?

Comment: @Joel Since the code doesn't work as intended, SO is the place to be. Not Code Review. At Code Review the code should work as intended to the best of the authors knowledge. That's not the case here.

Comment: @Mast thanks for clarifying

Comment: @Joel I did want an edge to always be added and that was the way I thought to do it...I'm still new at coding so there is probably a better way.

Comment: Just `A.add_edge(u,name)` will add the edge.  No need to do it if some condition holds.